# Python Django Queryset only get month and year from date

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, fusioncharts

I currently use the following code to create the queryset for my Fusioncharts bar chart:

```
 dataSourceBar['data'] = [] 

    objects_with_category_id_2 = dashboard_input.objects.filter(service_service_id=3,category_category_id=2)

    for obj in objects_with_category_id_2:
        data =  {'label': obj.session_start.strftime("%m.%Y"),
                 'value': obj.input_input_value}
        dataSourceBar['data'].append(data)
```

I tried to only get the month and year from the session_start, but now it only shows each month and year per date something is filled in.

[image]

Is there a way in which I can design the queryset that it sums the different values per month (in descending order)? So that the graph only shows three bars: 04.2019, 05.2019 and 06.2019?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can annotate and sum up, by using [**`TruncMonth`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncMonth), and [**`Sum`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#sum):

```
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth

dashboard_input.objects.filter(
    service_service_id=3,
    category_category_id=2
).annotate(
    label=TruncMonth('session_start')
).values('label').annotate(
    value=Sum('input_input_value')
).order_by('label')
```

This will result in a `QuerySet` that wraps dictionaries. Each dictionary has a `'label'` key that is mapped a `date(..)` object truncated to the month, and a `'value'` key that is mapped to the sum of the `'input_input_value'` values for that month.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I get an error on the SUM function: ProgrammingError: function sum(character varying) does not exist. And what values do I need to use in my for loop to make it work?

Comment: @Natasja: hold on, you used a `CharField` for your `input_input_value`? Shouldn't that be an `IntegerField`, `DecimalField`, or `FloatField`?

Comment: Yeah it should, but I can't change it now without having to recreate my table and losing data. But shouldn't the for loop be enough to sum my input data?

Comment: @Natasja: the point with `Sum(..)` is that you run this on the database level, and thus speedup up the sum.

Comment: But what value should I use in my for loop to make it work? I keep using session_start but that gives me an error. response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "C:\var\www\VSDK\vsdk\dashboard\views.py", line 36, in Chart data = {'label': obj.session_start.strftime("%m.%Y"), AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'session_start' @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @Natasja: it is `{'label': obj['label'].strftime("%m.%Y"), 'value': obj['value'] }`.